# Mixing local and shared config in fable with webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack, f#, fable-f#

With Fable and `webpack.config.js`, I've the situation where the `devServerPort` is different for some users locally vs the port used by the CI system. I was wondering if there's a standard way, or built-in way to deal with local configs, something like having a `webpack.local.config.js` that only overrides one specific value.

Then, each programmer has his or her own local config, which doesn't go into the repo, where you can override any shared values that are specified in the default `webpack.config.js` `CONFIG` variable.

The simple alternative being to just have different full configs lying around, or to just locally update the port number after each repo sync, but this obviously isn't ideal.

```js
// example of a default config:
var CONFIG = {
    // The tags to include the generated JS and CSS will be automatically injected in the HTML template
    // See https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin
    indexHtmlTemplate: './src/Client/index.html',
    fsharpEntry: './src/Client/Client.fsproj',
    outputDir: './deploy/public',
    assetsDir: './src/Client/public',
    devServerPort: 8080,  // some users cannot use port 8080 and want a different local config
    devServerProxy: { 
        // ... etc
```

<sub>*This question was asked on F# Slack first but didn't receive an answer hence posting here for wider audience.*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, one way to go is to have different configs for production and development environments. You can have the common part in yet another file and then use [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge).

So you would have like:

- `wepback.common.js`

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
...
module.exports = {
    entry: { ... },
    plugins: [ ... ],
    module: { ... },
};
```

- `webpack.development.js`

```js
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const commonConfiguration = require("./webpack.common");
...
module.exports = merge(commonConfiguration, {
    mode: "development",
    ...
    plugins:     [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        ...
    ],
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        ...
    },
    ...
});
```

- `webpack.production.js`

```js
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const commonConfiguration = require("./webpack.common");
...
module.exports = merge(commonConfiguration, {
    mode: "production",
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [ new MinifyPlugin() ]
    },
    ...
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        ...
    ],
    ...
});
```

Other things depend on your build scripts, but basically you can run `webpack` vs `webpack-dev-server` based on where you are, you can work with [environment variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/) and so on.

Comment: Oh, _env vars_, totally forgot about them, that would be an easy way out if only a single value needs to be different. I wasn't aware of `webpack-merge`, which sounds precisely like what I need. Tx!